# How can I add a form field to a form using jquery before the form is submitted

Tags: jquery

On my page I have two buttons.

1. Make a purchase without signing up
2. Make a purchase and add me to the mailing list.

Both buttons submit the same form however I need one of the buttons to add a hidden form field to the form before it is submitted to allow a POST variable to be used in the resulting PHP.

I cant get the following to work. TIA

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.place-order-with-newsletter').on('click', function(){

        jQuery('form#dc-checkout-form').submit(function(){

            jQuery('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', 'dc-opt-in')
            .attr('value', '1')
            .appendTo('form#dc-checkout-form')
            return true;
        })

    })

})
```

Comment: Put the newsletter button out of the form (or return false on click). on click event add the hidden field to the form and then submit the form using `.submit()` . There is no need to use a submit listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the button outside the form or change the type to "button"

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

By default, the buttons on the forms make submit.

And move all code to click event and finally submit the form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.place-order-with-newsletter').on('click', function(){
        jQuery('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', 'dc-opt-in')
        .attr('value', '1')
        .appendTo('form#dc-checkout-form')
        jQuery('form#dc-checkout-form').submit()
    })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont have direct access to the form, Im adding fields to the firm via woocommerce hooks and filters to add the submit inputs. Plus there are other actions that appear in the process. I think i may have to go back to the drawing board slightly.